# Sonarqube is ignoring file because of scm ignore setting and No coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am new to sonarqube. I did everything according to the documentation and I ran sonar-scanner in my project.

My project is a MERN stack project and this is the structure of that.

[image: Project]

This is the execution result.

```
C:\Users\DEEPIKA\Desktop\Online-Book-Store\Online-Book-Store>sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.2.2472
INFO: Java 11.0.11 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\DEEPIKA\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.0.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=140ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXwDD18TEpyimEl9r9ai
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\DEEPIKA\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=78ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=5968ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Project key: SPM_BookStore
INFO: Base dir: C:\Users\DEEPIKA\Desktop\Online-Book-Store\Online-Book-Store
INFO: Working dir: C:\Users\DEEPIKA\Desktop\Online-Book-Store\Online-Book-Store\.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'SPM_BookStore'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'SPM_BookStore' (done) | time=15ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=1062ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=15385ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 22 files indexed...  (last one was backend/models/wishList.model.js)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: 40 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/.vscode/launch.json)
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=109ms
INFO: 89 files indexed...  (last one was frontend/src/components/Admin/Contents/PrivatePolicy/UpdatePrivatePolicy/UpdatePrivatePolicy.jsx)
INFO: 247 files indexed
INFO: 82958 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module SPM_BookStore
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=94ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [cssfamily]
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [cssfamily] (done) | time=656ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily]
ERROR: CSS rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.getVersion(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:181)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.checkNodeCompatibility(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:159)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:134)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.initNodeCommand(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:157)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.startServer(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:107)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.server.CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.startServerLazily(CssAnalyzerBridgeServer.java:177)
    at org.sonar.css.plugin.CssRuleSensor.execute(CssRuleSensor.java:99)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:79)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:378)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:347)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand$ProcessWrapperImpl.start(NodeCommand.java:162)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:77)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 common frames omitted

INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=148019ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=15ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
ERROR: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:81)
    at 
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.getVersion(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:180)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.checkNodeCompatibility(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:158)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:133)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.initNodeCommand(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:174)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServer(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:119)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServerLazily(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:191)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.startBridge(AbstractEslintSensor.java:146)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.execute(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:79)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:378)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:347)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand$ProcessWrapperImpl.start(NodeCommand.java:162)
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:77)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 common frames omitted

INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=77619ms
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: No input files found for analysis
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=172ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: SCM Publisher SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: SCM Publisher 225 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 3/225 source files have been analyzed
INFO: 88/225 source files have been analyzed
INFO: SCM Publisher 225/225 source files have been analyzed (done) | time=25200ms
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 1 file
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=62ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 3397ms, dir size=872.0 kB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 297ms, zip size=346.1 kB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 265ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=SPM_BookStore
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AHwDV4bimEl9sDRs
INFO: Analysis total time: 15:11.307 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 15:18.712s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/47M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the execution file I saw these,

```
 82958 files ignored because of scm ignore settings

INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily]
ERROR: CSS rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:81)


INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=15ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
ERROR: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
    at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommand.start(NodeCommand.java:81)
```

I search in google and documentation for the solution but unable to find one. As now JS and nod is not working (check the error) the report is only checking css and html.
[image: Sonar]

Please help me to find the correct issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Firstly, it looks like that `node` is not accessible with the command prompt. Is it set as a global variable properly?